# Header text not showing in center

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, navigation

I'm new to react native. i'm working on navigation. the problem is in header text is not getting in center. i have try this

```
static navigationOptions = {
title: "Help",
alignSelf: 'center',
marginLeft: 50,
 headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
textAlign: 'center',
justifyContent:"center",

headerStyle: {
   backgroundColor: '#a01b1b',
   textAlign: 'center',
   headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
   justifyContent:"center",

  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `headerTitleStyle` like below to set your title in the center of the header

```
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Help',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                flex: 1,
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontFamily:'Lato-Black' //for setting font
            },
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#a01b1b', //set style to set backgroundColor to full header
            },
            headerBackTitle: 'Login',
            headerRight: <View/> //If you have back arrow at headerLeft otherwise remove this line
        }
```

Comment: Just one question more i want to title text a different font how can i do it?

Comment: now i'm getting everything just one thing i have set background color also but it's showing only for the help text not for the whole header.

Comment: see the edited answer set `style` object to set `backgroundColor`

Comment: @shabnamsingh just edited my answer set `headerStyle` instead of `style`

Comment: i'm not getting a font. just last one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183555/discussion-between-rutvik-bhatt-and-shabnam-singh).